# Target specific CSS classes with Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How would I go about styling something like the `react-datepicker` with styled-components? The datepicker library looks like it uses some type of BEM style (screenshot below) which I would normally just use their provided class names and style those using Sass. But, how would I target those class names with styled-components? Is that even possible?

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `styled-components` is just CSS™ you'd do it like with any other style sheet, by using the class names `react-datepicker` provided.

The only difference is that you'll have to wrap the datepicker in one wrapper styled component which applies all of these classes:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  &.react-datepicker {
    color: blue;
  }
`

<Wrapper>
  <Datepicker />
</Wrapper>
```

Comment: WHHAAAAAA???? You guys made this library too easy to use  Thank you for all of the effort you put into it.

Comment: I'm bumping up against the same issue. This mostly worked for me, except I couldn't use the `&`, my selector had to just be along the lines of `.react-datepicker {...}`

Comment: SUPER IMPORTANT: There is a space between the `&` and the `.react-datepicker` this is crucial for this answer to work as expected.

Comment: I've rolled back an edit that appears to meaningfully change this answer to the same solution provided by another answer.  If it was in fact a typo, please feel free to re-correct it.

Answer (score 8):

Searching for hours, I found that the best solution is to add a stylized parent component (it can be a div) overlying the component that needs a className and add the definition of the className directly into the stylized parent component.

> **VERY IMPORTANT:** 
> A space is needed between the ampersand `&` and the class for this to take effect!

```
const StyledParent = styled.div`
   & .your-class-name {
     border-color: red;
   }
`;

<StyledParent>
   <Datepicker yourClassName="your-class-name" />
</StyledParent>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to access and style another component you can do this if they are not in the same file:

Export whatever you need to access:

```
export { Wrapper as CircledButtonWrapper };
```

Import it where you need it:

```
import { CircledButtonWrapper } from "/Bla/CircledButton";
```

Use it where you need to style it:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div` 
 /* Some other styles */
    &:hover {
        ${CircledButtonWrapper} {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    } `;
```

Edit:
I see now that the question was refering to accessing className...